# Update user profile page using mongoose express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on personal project. one of common functionality i am implementing is allowing users to update their profile but having hard time doing it.

here is what i did so far
form

```
 <form
          action="/users/doctor-profile?_method=PUT"
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
        >
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                  
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="name"
                name="name"
              />
            </div>
           
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Phone</label>
              <input
                type="tel"
                class="form-control"
                id="formGroupExampleInput"
                name="phone"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>

              <input
                type="email"
                class="form-control"
                id="formGroupExampleInput"
                name="email"
              />
            </div>   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

                 </form>
```

here is my user model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
 
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

here is my post route

```
router.post("/users/doctor-profile", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email,phone } = req.body;
  const _id = ObjectId(req.session.passport.user._id);
 console.log(_id)
  USer.findOne({ _id: _id })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        req.flash("error_msg", "user not found");
        res.redirect("/users/doctor-profile");
      }
      if (typeof name !== "undefined") {
        user.name = name;
        console.log(user.name);
      }
      if (typeof email !== "undefined") {
        user.email = email;
      }
      if (typeof phone !== "undefined") {
        user.phone = phone;
      }
   
      user.save().then((User) => {
        req.flash("success_msg", "details updated successfully");
        res.redirect("/users/profile");
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

console output

```
application running on port 5000
mongodb connection successfull
5ef5bc20261beb1e6c1c25a3
```

but it does not update fields in database.

Comment: Could you post your console output?
Have you tested your mongodb connection?
Do you receive any errors?

Comment: yes everything is fine...no errors. it redirects to desired page but does not update fields

Comment: Try createing a middleware for the save() and log the differences. Try using the ?? operator instead of typeof xyz === 'undefined'. Add a console.log("edited user") to the if parts

Comment: ok i am pretty new and dont know how to create middleware for save and use...

Comment: try this code in your post routine: http://lehmanns-server.de/stackoverflow/gunal/mongoose_v1_0.js

Comment: received following output                                                                                       
property name is undefined
property email is undefined
property phone is undefined
User 'drjames' was saved successfully with 0 changes: []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216765/discussion-between-gunal-and-kai-lehmann).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
user.save(function (err, resolve) {
if(err)
  console.log('db error', err)
   // saved!
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your post route js file

here is the code you got the typo on:

```
USer.findOne({ _id: _id })
```

USer should be User